# JavaScript/HTML: Trouble linking JavaScript code to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hamburger-menu, responsiveness

I only recently started using JavaScript, and I apologize if I flouted some fundamentals. I was following a tutorial on creating a responsive sticky navigation menu with JQuery, which also includes a hamburger menu when the browser window is shrunken. Source code for reference: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2so52l4q74eu470/AABDHemSW_WsLUlBfPaLsNwsa?dl=0

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ResponsiveNav</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Menu-toggle button

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
              $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
  });

  // Scrolling Effect

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
              $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
              $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
  })


  </script>
```

However, the problem is if I try to put this JavaScript code onto a separate JavaScript file (shown below where I attempted to split the html code and the JavaScript code) and try to link it with the HTML file, the hamburger menu is no longer clickable. I really can't wrap my head around this on whether it is an indention problem in the JavaScript code or wrong format.

**HTML code** (where I attempted to link the HTML file to the JavaScript file with the JavaScript code.)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>ResponsiveNav</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

  </head>
```

**JavaScript file named script.js and placed in a folder called 'js'**

```
  // Menu-toggle button

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
              $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
  });

  // Scrolling Effect

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
              $('nav').addClass('black');
        }

        else {
              $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
  })
```

Kinda been stuck on this for an hour, so basically instead of having the JavaScript code in the HTML file, how can I properly link the HTML file with the JavaScript code on a JavaScript file?

Comment: Does the file load correctly? Or does it return a 404? You can check this in your browsers development tools.

Comment: Try putting a / before the js in the file path - you currently use a relative path sso it has to be relative to the url the page is served on

Comment: Make sure your js folder is at same location where your html file is placed

Comment: please let us know how your folder look like..

Comment: (file:///C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Website/js/script.js) I have put my html files in the Website folder and have three sub folders within the Website folder, which are css, images, and js. I have placed the javascript file in the js folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be smth wrong with the path to your script.js file. 
You can try smth like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"> </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"> </script>
```

Also look at the console in devTools, it might be some errors there if the path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just import it to your page the same way the [Bootstrap Get Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) page does.

For jQuery / js imports, it's often the order of the imports that's important.

Check this working sample:

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Navigation Sample</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>  
    
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </body>
      </html>
```

EDIT:

In case you want to know if the file was loaded correctly or not:

If youre in Chrome, hit `Crtl + Shift + J` to open the Developer Tools. There is a tab called `Console`. Imports that return an error code are listed here. If there is nothing listed, all files are loaded correctly.

Sample of how it looks like if resources fail to load:

[image: This is what it looks like if resources fail to load.]